Start Model with Agents on Conveyor
As the title suggests, when I run my simulation, I'd like there to be items already on a conveyor at a specific position on the conveyor.
I've tried using the Enter block and the conveyor enter, but I get a capacity error.
I'm new to AnyLogic so anything helps!
